# Find the successor of k in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting, binary-search

> Find a successor to element k in a sorted array of size n.

I'm stuck with the case where k is not an element of the array.. I was thinking about using BinarySearch and my idea is to get to the point where we narrowed it down to 2 elements, if the elements are bigger than k we return the left element, if they are smaller than k we return the element right of the right element. But I'm not sure if it works or how to implement it, or if there is a better solutions..

Comment: Use a binary search that returns an index to the rightmost element <= k, and then add 1 to that index.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the binary search example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-closest-number-array/). You can try with multiple language.

for example, you have an array with element `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]` and you need to search for `7`? It should return 8.

get mid element first. `mid index = 0 + len(array) / 2`. in this case index is `4`. and element = `5`

step1 - check the mid element equal to the k, then return k. But `7 != 5`.

then check target is greater or smaller than the mid element, If smaller then check left most is greater than target. if it is, then select most closet value with mid element and left most to mid and return. otherwise select left elements and do the same as step 1,

If larger then get right elements and do the same with right elements.

in this case should continue with `[6, 8, 9]`. again select mid. now it is `8`. not equal but target(7) is smaller than 8. then check left most value. It is 6 and target is greater than 6.

Now we need to get closet from 6 or 8. Its depend on your algo, In above example, it is `8`